# Adding Multiple Favorites of User in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm generally work on android development but decided to build my own REST API for a medium-large project. I need `to-do` idea for this application.

I have 2 tables:

**User**

`user_id`, `user_name`, `password`

**Favourite List**

`list_id`,
`list_name`

Let's assume we have 1000 lists about news. Every user can add one or many of these list items as their favourite.

I learned about `foreign key`, but I should relate many lists to user not only one.

I should make like:

`id_1` --->  user's lists: id 1,3,12,33

`id_2` ---> user's lists: id 1,12,55,77 etc.

Comment: Gord Thompson has given a good answer below. But to give a reason for this, the alternative is having a field containing a list of ids. While this is possible it makes it virtually impossible to check which users have a particular id in their list using an index. And without an index performance will be poor. MySQL does have a function called FIND_IN_SET which makes it easy to code to find an id in a list, but it still will not use any index for this.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) to associate the users with the lists. Each row in that table will contain a `user_id` and the `list_id` that they want to follow.